# How to retrieve value of type hyperlink from managed property in display template?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, display-template, picture

I have a site column of type HyperLink / Picture where the url for the icon is stored. I want to access this in the custom display template for search items.

Whenever I try to access the site column named ServiceIcon as described above, it retrieves null value. I have checked it using another tool whether any sort of value is being assigned to this managed property or not and it shows that correct value has been assigned to it. 
The following is the code:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','Path':'Path','Description':'Description','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime',
 'CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension',
'ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor','ServiceOffering':'ServiceOffering','ServiceColor':'ServiceColor','ServiceIcon':'ServiceIcon'

var pictureURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "ServiceIcon");
pictureURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);
alert("pic URL : " + pictureURL);
```

This alert displays null value. I have verified and the mapping with the crawled property has been done correctly. Please help.

Comment: Use var pictureUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.ServiceIcon this will give you value for service icon of current item.

Comment: @AkarshGupta: Can I do this is in the display template file? Are you sure that it will work?

Comment: @AkarshGupta: sorry to say but the thing that you mentioned does not work..

Comment: Ok, are you using this template for Search or in any other place ? Also you are pulling the data from any list right ?

Comment: Also check the Managed property which you have created is Retrievable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding it seems like you are trying to fetch a site column of type hyperlink/picture and in display templates instead of getting src you are getting entire html tag of an image.

I also came across similar issue.

I would suggest let the value be as it is i.e. an html tag of an image and embed it in a Div.

But before that use below JavaScript to encode the value

```
var yourImg = jQuery('<div/>').html(YourMappedProperty.inputValue).html();
```

and place yourImg inside a div, and your picture will be viewed.

I hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the managed property for the hyperlink as below

```
<span ><img src="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.ProfilePhoto =#_" height="150px" width="150px" /></span><br/><br/>
```

Here profile photo has the hyperlink which is in a SharePoint List. Make sure your managed property is retrievable.

Comment: are you putting the it like _#= ctx.CurrentItem.ProfilePhoto =#_ this, I mean you have to put it inside _#= =#_

Comment: what is the error message ??